# Can I get google new access token using refresh token if expired

Tags: php, wordpress, google-api, google-api-php-client

I want to fetch Google reviews using the Google business API on my WordPress Website. As we know that an `access_token` is required, but it always expires after 1 hour. Does anyone know how we can fetch the new `access_token` using refresh token?

For example, we have `access_token` and `refresh_token`, can we generate the new token using those credentials?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Normally, if you have saved the first access token you recieved, it should contain a refresh token.  If you use `setAccessToken()` to tell your client about that access token, the PHP client will auto-refresh the access token if it has expired.

You can use the `setTokenCallback()` method to grab and permanently save that new access token so it can be reused.  Doco for `setTokenCallback()` is here:
https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client#updating-tokens

You could alternatively do a manual token refresh with the `fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken()` method - a great, easy to follow, example is in the quickstart here (for Calendar API, but principles are the same): 
https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/php

Reading the quickstart should be a huge help to you in making sense of all if this!